# Format 6 Mio Codes for SQL Table

Tags: sql, csv, format, bigdata, sublimetext

I have a txt. File with 6 Mio unique Codes.

Codes like:

```
0007:=)GnuW
0045:)w1WKu
0007:=)GnuW
0045:)w1WKu
.....
```

1. I need a way to format them with a separator like || to upload them into a SQL Table.
   I tried to use SublimeText's ability to mark all 6 Mio Lines and jump to the End of each line to add the separator. ->that didn't worked Sublime crashes.
2. Once I have my formatted csv. How should I import this huge amount of records?
   Should I Split the File into 100 Files?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Thank you for the Information Narti.

I'm working on a Script for adding, seprators...

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you need the file to be converted from .txt to .csv? .txt should have line breaks.

If you are able to perform bcp this will be the fastest way to import data.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173839(v=sql.80).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173839%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Another way would be using bulk insert

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225968(v=sql.80).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225968%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

But also using "Import Data" feature in SSMS or using SSIS Data Flow should not take too long. if inserting into an empty table.

I'm assuming your data has linebreaks? So what about importing the data first and then split as needed?